# jQuery mobile button gets distorted when I use .show() and .hide()

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

When I use .hide() on a button in jQuery mobile initially its hides the button . when i use .show() property on it the UI gets distorted . Somehow the .button('refresh') similar to .listview('refresh') is not working .

I have recreated the bug in [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/x7Fab/)

```js
$('#page1').live('pageshow', function () {
    $("#showbtn1").click(function(){
       $("#btn1").show();
       $("#btn2").hide();
       $.mobile.changePage("#page2");        
    });
    $("#showbtn2").click(function(){
       $("#btn1").hide();
       $("#btn2").show();
       $.mobile.changePage("#page2");     
    });    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="page1" data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext" data-rel="back"></a> 
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">    
        <p>To recreate the bug <p>
        <p> 1.click on show button 1 </p>
        <p> 2.click back </p>
        <p> 3.click on show button 2 </p>
        <p> 4.button is distorted </p>
            
        <a id="showbtn1"  href="#" data-role="button">show only button 1</a>
         <a id="showbtn2" href="#" data-role="button">show only button 2</a>           
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
    
<div id="page2" data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext" data-rel="back"></a> 
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">    
        <a id="btn1" href="#" data-role="button">button 1</a>
        <a id="btn2" href="#" data-role="button">button 2</a>        
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

Any help is appreciated .

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

show() and hide() method adds "display: none" property which created effect like removing buttons from DOM. instead try css("visibility","visible") and "hidden" that will make just invisible and no distortion.

Comment: Thank you ... $("#btn1").css('display', 'block'); did the trick :)

Comment: I don't understand why css('display', 'block') works, because, show() is supposed to do exactly the same, but it worked for me too !

Answer (score 2):

After having no luck with visibility (because of positioning issues), the only solution I came across that worked without fail was to create a CSS class and then add/remove it to hide/show it:

```
$('.hide_me').addClass("vanish");
$('.show_me').removeClass("vanish");
```

and the css:

```
.vanish {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Its same like "css('display', 'block');" why to use addClass and removeClass at all ??

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing the out of balance `<p>` tag

HTML:

```
<p>To recreate the bug <p>
<p>To recreate the bug </p>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x7Fab/25/  i just had to change the css from inline to block ... :) thanks for the help

Comment: Yes, the </p> thing was a long-shot. By the way, I think your use of `.live()` in the fiddle might cause progressive re-attachment of handlers as pages are switched so not something you should do in production code.